# Your site was unable to contact the Apache Solr server

Tags: search

I have following installations:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
```

Solr running on `port 8983`

```
"solr_home":"/var/solr/data",
"version":"6.5.1 cd1f23c63abe03ae650c75ec8ccb37762806cc75 - jimczi - 2017-04-21 12:23:42",
```

Server OS:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
```

Though the Solr is running on the server I am unable to use it for my site (Drupal  7.38).

I have set Solr server URL as:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr
```

I am getting an error:

```
Your site was unable to contact the Apache Solr server.
```

What could be the issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you confirmed Solr is operational and configured cores?

Comment: Yes, everything is perfect. Even I can see an admin panel on the url : http://IP_address:8983/solr/#/